# Draw custom graph in iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, graph

I need to draw custom graph like those 3 images in iOS, can someone tell me how to accomplish this. Is it possible to draw those graph using core-plot open source library or i need to use quartz2d library explicitly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some beautiful tutorial on how to draw `custom graph in iOS`.

[Link1](http://code4app.net/ios/Coverage-Chart/51dd312f6803fa873b000000) , [Link2](http://code4app.net/ios/Rotation-Pie-Chart/51108c126803faf349000000). For More please refer this section [LINK](http://code4app.net/category/chart)

Comment: @Imran the links are now broken.. could you please update this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use core-plot framework / XYPieChart for pie chart